# Singleton Dagger2 components

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, dagger, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger2 in a google appengine project and I have several servlets that make use of, what should be, a singleton instance of a given object (MyObject).

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class})
public interface MyComponent {
  IMyObject object();
}
```

I then need DaggerMyComponent.create() to be a singleton too so that I can get the same IMyObject across all servlets. To do so, I added a

```
DaggerMyComponent INSTANCE = DaggerMyComponent.create()
```

to my MyComponent interface. However, that still allows create() to be called again by mistake and it doesn't necessarily look like a pretty solution to me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the docs seem to be saying that Dagger doesn't provide such a limitation so far as for version 2.0.1

> In order to get the proper behavior associated with a scope
>   annotation, it is the **caller's responsibility** to instantiate new
>   component instances when appropriate. A Singleton component, for
>   instance, should only be instantiated once per application, while a
>   RequestScoped component should be instantiated once per request.

http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html